# How to exclude a path from <Route> using react-router-dom?

Tags: react-router-dom

This code will render  only when the path is "/"

```
<Route exact path={"/"} component={Header}/>?
```

But what would do the opposite? That is, what is the best way to render  always EXCEPT for "/"? Is there an "else" equivalent?

Comment: Usually, the order by which the routes are defined matters. So you need to define the `/` path first and then all the rest. The router should direct to the first matching path.

Comment: OK so this seems to work
`<Switch><Route exact path={"/"}/><Route component={Header}/></Switch>`
But is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I am just putting it here just not to let the question unanswered. This is actually the same as you proposed in the comment.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" />
  <Route path="*" component={Header} />
</Switch>
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a better solution as you requested.